# Android Spinner Navigation?

Tags: android

i am currently creating an Android App in which I have data reading from a database. The main part though is that i am using the Spinner widget. As yous know, with an Android Spinner you can have as many options as you like within it.

What i want my Spinner to do is when i select an option, i would like to press a button (a Confirm or 'Ok' button) which will then navigate me to a page, which is related to that button.

For example, I'm doing sports events. So in one of my spinners, i wish it to have a list of events, and when i select a specific event, I want to be directed to a page that has content related to that event

Is this even possible? Or am i better off using a different widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) and in the [onItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method you can write your navigation code to move to corresponding activity. You can retreive the item details using position parameter in OnIntemSelected method.

Comment: Thanks @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), &quot;The day is &quot; + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } 




So for that bit of coding, would i just replace Adapter View with the spinner option? And where it says Toast, just replace that with my start New Activity, to open a new page?

Comment: Also i tried to space code out, but it wouldnt allow me to enter with spaces, apologies

Comment: run the code and if Toast shows the expected value, you can replace the toast with start new activity code. As ItemSelectedListener runs in UI thread it should work without any problems.